# This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, aura, lightning-out

I am trying to put a flow in a lwc using [this](https://unofficialsf.com/developer-topic-insert-screen-flows-into-your-lwc/). However when I put this flow on external website using lightning out the flow works fine for the first two screen but throws `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: flowruntime:flowRuntimeV2$controller$onActionSelected [e is null] Failing descriptor: {flowruntime:flowRuntimeV2$controller$onActionSelected}` when the next button is click on the third screen. My code is below.

demo.app

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" description="demo" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="testFlow"/>
</aura:application>
```

lwc html

```html
<!--
 - Created by zachary on 6/2/21.
 -->

<!-- Accrue Account Create -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="slds-card__body_inner" style="height: 100%">
            <lightning-layout vertical-align="stretch">
                <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto">
                    <div class="slds-progress slds-progress_vertical">
                        <ol class="slds-progress__list">
                            <template if:true={hasScreens}>
                                <template for:each={screens} for:item="screen">
                                    <template if:false={screen.active}>
                                        <template if:false={screen.completed}>
                                            <li class="slds-progress__item" key={screen}>
                                                <div class="slds-progress__marker"></div>
                                                <div class="slds-progress__item_content slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">{screen.name}</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </template>
                                        <template if:true={screen.completed}>
                                            <li class="slds-progress__item slds-is-completed" key={screen}>
                                                <div class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small">
                                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-success slds-progress__marker slds-progress__marker_icon" title="Complete">
                                                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:success"></lightning-icon>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="slds-progress__item_content slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">{screen.name}</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </template>
                                    </template>
                                    <template if:true={screen.active}>
                                        <li class="slds-progress__item slds-is-active" key={screen}>
                                            <div class="slds-progress__marker"><span class="slds-assistive-text">Active</span></div>
                                            <div class="slds-progress__item_content slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">{screen.name}</div>
                                        </li>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
                            </template>
                        </ol>
                        <div aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" role="progressbar"><span class="slds-assistive-text">Progress: 0%</span></div>
                    </div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <template if:true={hasScreens}>
                    <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" size="9" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 100%">
                        <div style='height: 100%; width: 100%'>
                            <div class="slds-card__body_inner" style='height: 100%; width: 100%; min-height: 500px'>
                                <c-screen-flow onflowstatuschange={handleFlowChange} flow-name='Accrue_CreateAccountInLWC' height="100%" width="100%" flow-params={params} style='height: 100%; width: 100%'></c-screen-flow>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

lwc js

```js
/**
 * Created by zachary on 6/2/21.
 */

import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import getScreenName from '@salesforce/apex/Accrue_getScreenNames.returnScreenNames'
export default class AccrueAccountCreate extends LightningElement {
    screens = []
    hasScreens = false
    screenActive
    firstCall = true
    step = 1
    params = ''
    connectedCallback() {
        getScreenName().then(result => {
            result.forEach(screen => {
                this.screens.push({name: screen, active: false, completed: false})
            })
            this.hasScreens = true
            this.updateActive()
        })
    }

    handleFlowChange(event) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail))
        // TODO add code to handle progress bar
    }

    updateActive() {
        if(this.firstCall) {
            this.screens[0].active = true
            this.firstCall = false
        } else {
            for(let i = 1; i <= this.step; i++) {
                if(i === this.step) {
                    this.screens[i-1].active = true
                    this.screens[i-1].completed = false
                } else {
                    this.screens[i-1].completed = true
                    this.screens[i-1].active = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Extrernal website would be using, guest user profile, check if the guest user profile has the desired access. [This article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351305&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) might help you

Comment: @HemantJain I have. It has all objects,apex classes, visualforce, and named creds. This also does not work inside salesforce either.

Comment: Does it have access to the flow is the flow active too?

Comment: @SergioAlcocer It does. The flow work for the first two screens in it but fails on when clicking the next button on the third screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been dealing with a very similar issue all day, trying to expose a lightning runtime flow embedded in VF through a public site, but finally - *finally* - discovered that navigation buttons simply will not work if there is a Section component added anywhere on the Screen. Apparently there is absolutely zero information out there about this bug. Took a few hours of brute force to figure this one out.

So, remove any and all Section components from your Screen elements, figure out a workaround using text templates if necessary, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I just confirmed this... Do you have a link to a known issue for this @nllpntr?

Comment: you saved my evening! Crazy little flows...